# Why does gsub not work as expected

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have this string:

```
c <- "thethirsty thirsty itthirsty (thirsty) is"
```

I want the output to be as

```
     "thethirsty thirsty itthirsty no is"
```

This is what I am trying.

```
gsub(" (thirsty) ", " no ", c)
```

This is what I am getting. Why does not it work? And suggest an alternative to do this.

```
"thethirsty no itthirsty (thirsty) is"
```

Comment: You need to escape `(` and `)` using `\\(` and `\\)`.

Answer (score 1):

By default `gsub` interprets the first parameter as a regular expression. You don't want that and should set `fixed=TRUE`:

```
gsub(" (thirsty) ", " no ", c, fixed=TRUE)
#[1] "thethirsty thirsty itthirsty no is"
```